# Linq: let Count result into a specified column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I've got a table `Installation` which can contains one or many Equipements.

And for functionnal reasons, I've overwritten my table `Installation` and added a field `NbrEquipements`.

I want to fill this field with `Linq`, but I'm stuck...

Due to **special** reasons, there is no relation between these to tables. So, no `Installation.Equipements` member into my class. Therefore, no `Installation.Equipements.Count`...

I'm trying some stuff. Here is my code:

```
    var query = RepoInstallation.AsQueryable();

    // Some filter
    query = query.Where(i => i.City.RegionId == pRegionId));

    int?[] etatIds = { 2, 3 };
    query = (from i in query
                      select new Installation
                      {
                          NbrEquipements= (from e in RepoEquipement.AsQueryable()
                                               where e.InstallationSpecialId == i.SpecialId
                                               && (etatIds.Contains(e.EquEtat))
                                               select e.SasId
                                               ).Count()
                      });
```

But with this try, I got this error:

```
The entity or complex type 'myModel.Installation' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query
```

I've tried some other stuff but I'm always turning around...

Another thing that can be useful for me: It would be great to fill a field called `Equipements` which is a `List<Equipement>`.
After that, I would be able to `Count` this list...
Is it possible ?

Tell me if I'm not clear.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is the final code:**

```
    //In the class:
    [Dependency]
    public MyEntities MyEntities { get; set; }

    //My Methode code:
    var query = MyEntities .SasInstallations.AsQueryable();

    // Some filter
    query = query.Where(i => i.City.RegionId == pRegionId));


     var liste = new List<Installation>();
            var queryWithListEquipements =
                from i in query
                select new
                {
                    Ins = i,
                    EquipementsTemp = (from eq in MyEntities.Equipements.AsQueryable()
                                                          where eq.SpecialId == i.SpecialId
                                                                && (etatIds.Contains(eq.SasEquEtat))
                                                          select eq
                        ).ToList()

                };

            var listWithListEquipements = queryWithListEquipements.ToList();

            foreach (var anonymousItem in listWithListEquipements)
            {
                var ins = anonymousItem.Ins;
                ins.Equipements = anonymousItem.EquipementsTemp;
                ins.NumberEquipements = ins.Equipements.Count();
                liste.Add(ins);
            }

    return liste;
```

By the way, this is very very fast (even the listing of Equipements). So this is working exactly has I wished. Thanks again for your help everyone!

Comment: Do you want to retrieve `NbrEquipements` only? or all the properties of `Installation` plus `NbrEquipements`?

Comment: I want all the properties of Installation plus NbrEquipements.

Comment: Just create a sub type of `Installation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). EF does not like to instantiate entity classes inside a query.

```
var results = (from i in query
    select new
    {
        NbrEquipements= (from e in RepoEquipement
                             where e.InstallationSpecialId == i.SpecialId
                             && (etatIds.Contains(e.EquEtat))
                             select e.SasId
                             ).Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Notice how I used `select new` instead of `select new Installation`.

You can then use the data inside the list (which is now in memory) to create instances of type `Installation` if you want like this:

```
var installations = results.Select(x =>
          new Installation
          {
              NbrEquipements = x.NbrEquipements
          }).ToList();
```

Here is how to obtain the list of equipment for each installation entity:

```
var results = (from i in query
    select new
    {
        Installation = i,
        Equipment = (from e in RepoEquipement
                             where e.InstallationSpecialId == i.SpecialId
                             && (etatIds.Contains(e.EquEtat))
                             select e).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

This will return a list of anonymous objects. Each object will contain a property called `Installation` and another property called `Equipment` (which is a list). You can easily convert this list (of anonymous objects) to another list of whatever type that you want.

Comment: I get this error when calling the last instruction: Linq To Entities exception does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Equipement] AsQueryable()', and cannot be translated into store expression

Comment: By the way, do you think that getting all the Equipements instead of the Count() would be more costly ? Because I need this List of Equipements by the way... Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: @Grimness, what is the type of `RepoEquipement`? is it a `DbSet`?

Comment: @Grimness, Yes, getting the list of equipment is more expensive.

Comment: Hello, the RepoEquipement is of type "IRepository<Equipement>". IRepository being "public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : AEntity<int>". Visual Studio alerts me of an error if I remove ".AsQueryable()"

Comment: I tried to pass through the DbSet (which is "behind" the AsQueryable()) but I get the same error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[RES.Common.SasEquipement] MyDbSet()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: @Grimness, So you want to execute a query across multiple repositories? Do they use the same `DbContext` instance? Can't you create a single repository and have the queries inside it?

Comment: Let say I want to get manually all the Equipments of an Installation (manually instead of through EF). I will decide after if I use only a Count(). The two repo should use the same context instance. I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: I've finally add a "global repository" in my class. Needed to add a reference to EntityFramework ... so I break some of my layers architecture but it's ok as this works. I'll put details on my initial question. Thanks again !